# Submit button VBA Code for userform in Word

Tags: vba, file-upload, ms-word, form-submit, userform

I was creating a userform in microsoft word but having issues with the submit button. The problem is that I am adding a field to insert an image file. I found a code online to insert the image but not sure what to add so that it inserts the image in the document when I click submit.

Given below is the code I found for inserting an image. It had a text box, an image field and a button to add image. This worked for inserting the picture even though i didnt need the text box showing the file path. But didnt know how to edit where just a free size image gets uploaded from a folder so using this.

```
Private Sub CMDSUB_Click()
   FormLoadPicture Me.TextBox1, Me.Image1, Me
End Sub

Sub FormLoadPicture(TxtboxToFill As MSForms.TextBox, _
  ImageBox As MSForms.Image, objForm As MSForms.UserForm)
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim PicPath As String

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            PicPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            TxtboxToFill.Text = PicPath
            ImageBox.Picture = LoadPicture(PicPath)
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I am using the text given below for the submit button so that the bookmarks get populated. What do I add there so that the image gets added to the document.

```
   Private Sub cmdsubmit_Click()
    'Copy form elements to test template from userform
    Dim bmks As Bookmarks
    Dim bmRange As Range
    'Pass the userform values to the document's bookmarks.
Set bmks = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
Set bmRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Field01").Range
bmRange.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
Set bmRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Field02").Range
bmRange.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value & " "
     Me.Hide
    End Sub
```

Have to submit the document in office.

Comment: Are you wanting it to preview it on the userform before inserting it in the document?

Comment: Yes. Had found a code for it and it worked fine on my machine but gave a runtime error 5948 message on another machine when adding the image.